# Check in location service is active

Tags: iphone, ios, location

I'm trying to figure out how to detect if the location services are active and searching for the users location.  This is to create a location toggle button.

When the app starts it turns on location services using:

```
[locationController.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

I then have a button which I would like to do the following:

```
if (location.services active) {
    //turn off LS
} else {
    // turn on
}
```

This is not a question about locationServicesEnabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, Location Services is a system service that can be used by multiple applications at a time. Therefore when you are using it, you do not know if it was on or off before you accessed it. The OS will turn it on or off based on the usage you have no information about it's status whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds impossible to set an On/Off switch then as I cannot detect the state when I load the view.